# Programmatically prepare drive for BitLocker

Tags: windows, powershell, disk-partitioning, bitlocker

How can I programmatically prepare a drive for BitLocker.

I get VMs with OS and System volumes in the same volume and would like to enable BitLocker. Like this:

[image: Single OS and System Volume]

The BitLocker Wizard will prepare the drive like so:
[image: BitLocker Drive Preparation Wizard]

The outcome will look like this:
[image: Separate OS and System Volumes]

I'd like to be able to do this in PowerShell or really any scripted way.

I've tried using the New-Partition cmdlet, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the BitLocker Module?  I think the Enable-BitLocker is what you are looking for.

PS> Import-Module BitLocker
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'BitLocker' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import
-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

PS> Get-Command -Module BitLocker

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source

---

Function        Add-BitLockerKeyProtector                          1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Backup-BitLockerKeyProtector                       1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        BackupToAAD-BitLockerKeyProtector                  1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Clear-BitLockerAutoUnlock                          1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Disable-BitLocker                                  1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Disable-BitLockerAutoUnlock                        1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Enable-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock                         1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Get-BitLockerVolume                                1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Lock-BitLocker                                     1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector                       1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Resume-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Suspend-BitLocker                                  1.0.0.0    BitLocker
Function        Unlock-BitLocker                                   1.0.0.0    BitLocker

Comment: Thanks. The volume needs to be prepared before BitLocker can be enabled. I found a tool that will do the preparation that I need.